# Function Riemann integrable that are not Lebesgue integrable.

Tags: lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

I had an exam today and one of my question was: *Give a function $f$ that is Riemann integrable but not Lebesgue integrable*

How is it possible ? I always thought that Riemann $\implies $ Lebesgue, isn't it ?

Comment: Was the question "Prove or disprove"?

Comment: I assume here the question includes ["Improper (Riemann) integrals"?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral#Improper_Riemann_integrals_and_Lebesgue_integrals)

Comment: no, just to give an exemple of a function that is Riemann integrable but not Lebesgue integrable. I'm a little bit suprised of such a question since I always thought that a Riemann integrable function was Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: @ClementC.: I don't know, but probably. Is it that important ?

Comment: No. Lebesgue integrability of $f$ requires the integrability of $|f|$ as well. Consider integrating $\frac{\sin x}x$ on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @user301068 See the example given in the Wikipedia section I linked (which is the same as MPW's: $f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$.)

Answer (score 5):

You may like to visit http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/ccc/gauge/ for an excellent introduction to the different integrals. I am reproducing an image from that website for your quick reference.

[image: Relationship between various integrals]

Answer (score 3):

A function $f$ is Lebesgue integrable if and only if $f^+=0\vee f$ and $f^-=0\wedge f$ are integrable. So if $f\geq 0$ is Riemann integrable then it will be also Lebesgue integrable. But if $f$ has not a constant sign, then $f$ can be Riemann integrable but not Lebesgue integrable as $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ on $[0,\infty [$. And this is because $\int f^+=\int f^-=+\infty$. Therefore $\int f=\int f^+-\int f^-$ is not defined.

Comment: How can you show that $\int f^+ = +\infty$?